# Why can't I use T as a return type for my prefix operator?

Tags: swift, generics, prefix-operator

Simply exploring Swift, in the context of the Observable pattern rite of passage. What I wanted to explore was implementing a prefix operator for the sake of syntactic sugar.

```
class Observable<T> {
    var value:T
    init(_ v:T) {
        value = v
    }
}

postfix operator &* { }

postfix func &* (arg:Observable<T>) -> T {
    return arg.value
}
```

However, the compiler informs me that `-> T` is `use of an undeclared type`. Can the generic really not be used as the return type? Is there something else going on here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to make the function generic:

```
postfix func &*<T>(arg:Observable<T>) -> T {...}
```

As you've written it, `T` is expected to be a type itself, not a type parameter.